# How can I change login while authenticating on SSH?

Tags: debian, ssh, login, putty

It's hard for me to express exactly what I mean, so I'll explain it in a few steps:

1. I'm connecting with SSH, and server ask me for login.
2. I write login, and then it asks me for password.
3. I realize that this login is wrong! I want to change it, but I can't go back to login...

How to go back to login prompt?

If it matters, I'm trying to login with Putty.

Comment: End the login and create a new ssh session. Ending the login can be done by pressing Ctrl-D.

Comment: Uwe - thanks for replay. I'm always doing it like that, but I tought that it's "hard way". :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not possible. You will have to end this login session by Ctrl-D and start all over with a new ssh session.

For your use (putty) it might be noteworthy that - if you insist on autheticiation by username/password and not using keyfiles - it still saves a little time to save a session profile for easy later use. The host name (or IP address) can be extended to include the user name thus you wouldn't need to type it again and again. The syntax is: username@hostname